# Shortcut in vs code to write input statement of java

Tags: java, visual-studio-code, java.util.scanner, shortcut

I have tried various shortcuts but didn't find any for auto completing

`Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);`

in java in vs code...

Comment: AFAIK, there isn't a shortcut for doing that.  That pattern is pretty unusual in *real world* programs, and the VScode designers probably didn't even *think* to implement a built-in short-cut for writing that.  You could of course try creating a custom snippet to do that; see https://code.visualstudio.com/docs/editor/userdefinedsnippets

Comment: Just write it out fully. How often would you write that line day-to-day? You have spent far more time writing this question, and I have spent far more time writing this comment than you would ever save from having a shortcut for that specific line.

Answer (score 1):

You can use the `type` command:

```json
{
  "key": "ctrl+i j",  // or any other combo
  "command": "type",
  "args": { "text": "Scanner sc = new Scanner(System.in);" },
  "when": "editorTextFocus"
}
```